# How does C# resolve different extension method overloads?

Tags: c#, match, overloading

I've got a code snippet as below:

```
public static class M
{
    public static int Plus(this int i, int p=6)
    {
        return i + p;
    }
}
public static class N
{
    public static int Plus(this int i)
    {
        return i + 10;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 3.Plus();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Run the program, it outputs "13", which indicates class N's extension method is called. Why class M's method is not matched?

Then if I remove class N, OK, class M's extension method is called, it outputs "9" as expected.

So my question is, is there a rule in C# or .net framework to determine, which extension method is to be called if multiple matches are there? Is this related to overload resolution rule or something else?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9):

The same overloading rules apply to extension methods as for all other methods. `N` is used because it is a better match. `M` may have an optional parameter, but the no parameter option is a better fit as the rules favour the option with the fewest parameters.

From [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.

However, "closeness" comes into play with extension methods too, as described in [Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/):

The consequence of this is that if you restructure your code to:

```
namespace X
{
    public static class N
    {
        public static int Plus(this int i)
        {
            return i + 10;
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class M
    {
        public static int Plus(this int i, int p = 6)
        {
            return i + p;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            int i = 3.Plus();
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the number displayed is `9`. In other words, the version with an optional parameter is chosen as it's in the same namespace and thus "closer".

Comment: Eric Lippert also has a good blog on [overload matching](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=closer-is-better)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, nice find. I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with extension methods specifically. At the tie breaking phase of the overload resolution algorithm, a method that matches the call without application of default arguments is preferred over a method that requires application of said default arguments to match the call.

As the [C# specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) puts it, at page 154:

> [...] if all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in MQ then MP is better than MQ.